# Are "should I buy X for $Y" questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

A few years ago, I had an opportunity to buy a laptop. I [managed to sneak it in](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/89397/44427) to Ask Different as a different question, but the answer to that question would necessarily answer my real question: "Is it a good deal?". Now that this site exists, though, I wonder if we can handle these.

So, are questions that ask "should I buy X for $Y" on-topic?

Answer (score 6):

I would say no, because we all value money differently. What I would spend $50 on, you might not even spend $10. Plus it is always easier to spend other people's money.

I would say these questions worded like "should I buy X for $Y" should be closed as primarily opinion-based.